# how to union multiple tables on different databases and server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

In MySQL, I have two different databases -- let's call

```
$dbcon1 = mysql_connect('db1_host','db1_user','db1_pass') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db1_dbName',$dbcon1)or die(mysql_error());

$dbcon2 = mysql_connect('db2_host','db2_user','db2_pass') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db2_dbName',$dbcon2)or die(mysql_error());
```

Now i am executing a UNION between a table that is in 'db1_dbName', to a table that is in 'db2_dbName'. let's call :

```
  Select coloum1,coloum2 FROM db1_dbName.students 
  UNION ALL
  Select coloum1,coloum2 FROM db2_dbName.students LIMIT 30,50
```

I got no result. I have checked my database connections, it all works fine.

Would any one tell me what's wrong in that ?

Comment: in sql server it's easy by linked servers but in mysql not sure.

Comment: you need to use [federated storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

Comment: @Adeel `FEDERATED Storage Engine` is different than what OP is asking for.

Comment: thanks for answering. @Adeel could you tell how to use 'federated storage engine'.Because i have search in google and also in Mysql website.But i can't get any example 'how to use this ?'

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-description.html try this

Comment: @Adeel I got result when i run above query in localhost.
how it can be possible that i am not getting any result in remote server but in localhost my query gives result.